# Updating multiple fields in a column simultaneously Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Say I have the following table:

```
App   owner   owner_id
______________________
1     John    NULL
2     Jack    000123
3     John    NULL
4     April   000124
5     John    NULL
6     April   000124
7     John    000123
8     Ash     NULL
9     Ash     NULL
10    Ash     NULL
```

If I need to update John and Ash's `owner_id`s, is there a way to update each owner's `owner_id` for every occurrence in the table by only entering the information once?
I have to do this for about 1000 owners, but with the amount of duplicates I am looking at around 10000 blank `owner_id`s.

I do not have the proper rights to restructure or split the table.

Comment: Where do you get the `owner_id`s from?

Answer (score 4):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, it's just:

```
update owners_table set owner_id = '000001' where owner = 'john'
update owners_table set owner_id = '000002' where owner = 'ash'
```

This will set the `owner_id` to `000001` in every row where the owner is `John`, and to `000002` in every row where the owner is `Ash`.

It's just more copy & paste when you have a lot of owners, because you have to create one query for each owner.

---

Another way would be to create a temporary table with just the owner and his new id:

```
owner   newid
--------------
John    000001
Ash     000002
```

You can enter hundreds or thousands of owners and their new `owner_ids` into the table.

Then, you can update them in your main table all at once with the following query:

```
UPDATE owners_table 
INNER JOIN ownertmp ON owners_table .owner = ownertmp.owner 
SET owners_table.owner_id = [ownertmp].[newid];
```

After that, you can delete the temporary table again - it's just needed to run the query.